# PKI Smart Card Application (Windows and Mac OS)

Tags: smartcard, pki, smartcard-reader

i have to build an application that read a certificate stored in a smart card and then sign a string. As far as i've never done a thing like this before where should i start from? Which library should i use? Are there examples?

Thanks in advance for the answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify language in which yoe have to implement the application. I would recommend [PKCS11Interop](http://www.pkcs11interop.net/). It is a c# library. Example of signing can be found [here](https://github.com/jariq/Pkcs11Interop/blob/master/src/Pkcs11InteropTests/HighLevelAPI/_20_SignAndVerifyTest.cs#L33). It is well documented and actively developed. Even test are documented so it should be easy to understand even if you do not have much experience in the area.

Comment: Sounds good, but when i try to use it (with the code examples) i get an error "The name 'Settings' does not exist in the current context", i've added with nuget the library but nothing :( maybe you know why? Thank you so much anyway for this suggestion

Comment: The settings can be found [here](https://github.com/jariq/Pkcs11Interop/blob/master/src/Pkcs11InteropTests/Settings.cs)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but where do i have to put that file? If i add it as a class in my project it can't find all "LowLevelAPI".. Sorry for my noob questions and thanks again for the support :)

Comment: Ok I've included all folders named "LowLevelAPI" inside the project and all errors seems to be gone, tomorrow I will check better..

Answer (score 0):

There are many closed-source implementations, and a few open source projects, although as usual many of these have not been active for years.
One you could have a look at is *IsoApplet*, which is also quite well documented: https://github.com/philipWendland/IsoApplet